# Why doesn't compiler give warning for super.staticMethod()

Tags: java, static, compiler-warnings, super, eclipse-kepler

I know that we should access static members in static way via class name and understand why (next code only for example, I understand it is bad practice). But why when I try access static method via super keyword there is no compiler warnings? Consider you have next code:

```
class Parent {
    static int staticField;
    static void staticMethod() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void testStatic() {
        this.staticMethod(); // warning
        super.staticMethod(); // NO warnings
        new Child().staticMethod(); // warning
        new Parent().staticMethod(); // warning

        this.staticField++; // warning
        super.staticField++; // warning
        new Child().staticField++; // warning
        new Parent().staticField++; // warning
    }
}
```

So, the question is why compiler doesn't give warnings for line `super.staticMethod();`

Comment: My IDE warns me about every line. What IDE do you have and have you checked that this warning isn't explicitly disabled?

Comment: **super** does refer to an instance -- the same instance that **this** refers to -- the current object.

Comment: My IDE is Eclipse Kepler, and default prefs are the next http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm

Comment: @ajdev I'm using IDEA and it warns me about that. Maybe Eclipse just ignores that, but it is up to the IDE if it warns about something or not.

Comment: @Tom thank you. I' m a newbie , so I just whant to make sure that this isn't some strange and specisic behavior of super keyword

Answer (score 2):

Your situation called **Indirect Access To Static Method** and the warning for it is **off** by default. To enable it:

1. Right click on the project, go to properties.
2. Java compiler.
3. Error/warnings.
4. Configure workspace settings 
   [image]
5. Check (activate) Enable project specific settings.
6. Change the **indirect access to static method** to warning.
   [image]

I am using eclipse luna and it works for me

Comment: I tried do this. The only thing has changed - warning: Before compiler showed " The static method staticMethod() from the type Parent should be accessed in a static way ". After that (all steps that you have described) it says "The static method staticMethod() from the type Parent should be accessed directly ".  But still line  `super.staticMethod();` has no warnings.